# Is it possible to have two different types of marginal distribution with ggExtra::ggMarginal()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to have two different types of marginal distribution in [ggMarginal()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggExtra/versions/0.9/topics/ggMarginal)? *E.g.*, density for x and histogram for y?

```
library(ggExtra)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

# Histogram for both x and y
ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")

# Density for x
ggMarginal(p, type = "density", margins = "x")
# Histogram for y
ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram", margins = "y")
```

Basically, I would like the two marginal distributions shown below on the same plot.
[image]

I tried having both types in a list (
`ggMarginal(p, type = list("density", "histogram"))`), but that `type` must be of length 1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to create both plots and swap their upper margin grobs:

```r
library(ggExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()

ph <- ggMarginal(p, type = "histogram")
pd <- ggMarginal(p, type = "density")

ph$grobs[ph$layout$name == "topMargPlot"] <- 
  pd$grobs[ph$layout$name == "topMargPlot"]

ph
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>